# How to enter php variable values ​into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.8

I'de like to create a loop using Twig syntaxe in my javascript is it possible ? if yes how can I access `{{$ t-> name}}` in javascript ?

So far I have tested this:

### Javascript

```js
var faqs_row = 0;
function addfaqs() {
    html = '<tr id="faqs-row' + faqs_row + '">';
    html += '<td><select class="form-control" name="tim">@foreach ($tim as $t)<option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>@endforeach</select></td>';
    html += '<td class="mt-10"><button class="badge badge-danger" onclick="$(\'#faqs-row' + faqs_row + '\').remove();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>';
    
    html += '</tr>';
    
    $('#faqs tbody').append(html);
    
    faqs_row++;
}
```

### View

```html
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="tim">
        @foreach ($tim as $t)
            <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

please help me
[image]

Comment: can you add some details, do you want to do everything in Javascript ? do you  want the loop to be executed ? where is your javascript file ? what is `$tim` ?

Comment: Ok we start to go somewhere, so when clicking on `new` you execute the `addfaqs` function ? I ask again where is written your javascript ? in the bottom of your page, in a separate file ? what is `$tim` an `array`, an `arrayCollection`, a `fruit` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var faqs_row = 0;
function addfaqs() {
html = '<tr id="faqs-row' + faqs_row + '">';
    html += '<td><select class="form-control" name="tim">';
    @foreach ($tim as $t)
        html += '<option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>';
    @endforeach
    html += '</select></td>';
    html += '<td class="mt-10"><button class="badge badge-danger" onclick="$(\'#faqs-row' + faqs_row + '\').remove();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>';

    html += '</tr>';

$('#faqs tbody').append(html);

faqs_row++;
}
```

Comment: so it can't add new

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use php. I created seperate demo.

```
<?php
    $fruits = ['apple','banana','orange','grape'];
    $options = "";
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        $options .= "<option>".$fruit."</option>";
    }
?>

<select>
    <?php echo $options?>
</select>
```

May be this will help